# Convergence of the integral $\int _{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, infinity

How can I show (with one of the tests for convergence , **not by solving**) that the integral $$\int _{1}^\infty\frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx$$ converges?

Comment: What is the $i$ for??

Comment: It's probably meant to be an $x$, or else the $x$'s are meant to be $i$'s.

Comment: Where is your $dx$ (or perhaps $di$)?

Comment: It was running late and caught the next bus, clearly

Answer (score 1):

Show that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln^5(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=0$. Hence there is $a>1$ sucht that

$0 < \frac{\ln^5(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \le 1$ for $x>a$. It follows:

$0 < \frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2} \le \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ for $x>a$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Abel's theorem: let $g = fh$ be defined on $[a, b)$ with $b \in (a, \infty]$. If it holds that:

- $h$ is continuous, positive, decreasing and $\lim_{x \to b} h(x) = 0$
- $f$ is locally integrable on $[a, b)$ (i.e. integrable in the neighbourhood of any point) and $F$ is bounded on $[a, b)$, where $F: [a,b) \to \Bbb R$,

$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$

Then, $\int_a^b g(x)dx$ is convergent.

Use this with $a = 1$, $b = \infty$, $h(x) = 1/x^2$

Comment: does the integration of $$f=ln^5(x)$$ is bounded?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\ln^5(x)$ grows more slowly than $x^{1/2}$, you could use a comparison test. For some positive $a>1$, we have:

$$\int_a^\infty \frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2} dx \leq \int_a^\infty \frac{x^{1/2}}{x^2} dx = \int_a^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$$

You should know that the last expression is convergent by previous results.

Comment: You can't necessarily start the upper bound integral at $1$.  You would need to be sure of the crossover point.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, what do you mean, the "crossover point"?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Actually, it appears that for $x\geq 1$, $x^2>\ln^5(x)$.  So, the original formulation was correct (but didn't have justification).

Answer (score 0):

If you really meant:
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^5}{x^2}dx, 
$$
then observe that for $x$ sufficiently large, $\frac{\ln(x)^5}{\sqrt{x}}$ is less than $1$.  In other words, for some $c>1$, $\ln(x)^5<\sqrt{x}$ for all $x>c$.  Therefore, the tail of this integral is bounded above by
$$
\int_c^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}},
$$
which converges.  Then,
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(x)^5}{x^2}dx\leq \int_1^c \frac{\ln(x)^5}{x^2}dx+\int_c^\infty\frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}<\infty.
$$

Answer (score 0):

For any $a, b >0$,
$(\log x)^a/x^b \to 0$
as $x \to \infty$.

Therefore
$\int_1^{\infty}\dfrac{(\log x)^adx}{x^{1+b}}
$
converges for
$a,b >0$
(and diverges for
$b=0$).

Answer (score 0):

We know 
$$\ln u=\int_1^u\dfrac{1}{t}dt\leq\int_1^u\dfrac{t^\alpha}{t}dt=\dfrac{u^\alpha-1}{\alpha}<\dfrac{u^\alpha}{\alpha}$$
for all $\alpha>0$ so with $\alpha=\dfrac{1}{10}$:
$$\int _{1}^\infty\frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx \leqslant 10^5\int _{1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^\frac32}dx<\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \mathcal{I}=\int _{1}^\infty\frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx$

As $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\ln^5(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=0\implies \exists a>0, \text{such that } \forall x>a \quad \frac{\ln^5(x)}{\sqrt{x}}<1\iff\frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}<\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

$\displaystyle\implies \frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2} =\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right)\implies \int _{a}^\infty\frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}dx$ converges

As $\displaystyle \int _{1}^a\frac{\ln^5(x)}{x^2}\;dx$ is bounded  $\implies\mathcal{I}$ converges